# Django создать модель ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-filter

Имею модель Post для блога:

```
сlass Post(models.Model):
..............
..............

    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name="blog_posts",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Хочу подключить фильтр по тегам, написал такую модель:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name
```

Добавил в Post:

```
tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

при makemigrations выдает ошибку:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'tag' to post without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

И собственно вопрос как сделать field 'tag' nullable? Уже добавил пару постов в блог, их можно и удалить и создавать посты заново , но интересно как решить это проблему не удаляя постов?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас поле `tag` не может иметь значение `null`. Варианты решения Django-умняшка Вам написал:

- или установите одноразовое значение (выбираете `1` и вводите желаемое значение, затем пишите `yes` и нажимаете Enter),
- или добавьте к полю дефолтное значение default='MY_TAG':

Еще есть вариант добавить к полю `null=True`, а затем выполнять `makemigrations`
В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/) есть примеры.

Удалять ничего не нужно.